# Refresh/Reload Google map

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, google-maps, refresh, reload

I have a Google map and I want to refresh or reload map from my code. How is it possible?

I go through this link http://www.codigoactionscript.org/langref/googlemaps/com/google/maps/MapEvent.html but there is nothing for refresh/reload map there.

Comment: Why would you reload the map?  Do you want to reset position, zoom, and overlays?

Comment: The reason is, sometime client loose access to internet due to connection problem. I need some Refresh/Reload every 5 min or “onClick” for my application to cover this issue. I figure it out by ` googleMap.dispatchEvent( new MapEvent( MapEvent.MAP_READY, onMapLoadReady ) ); ` but this is not what I`m looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't exactly "refreshing the map"; however, accomplishes the same thing.

Use a timer to remove the map from the stage and add it again, calling the full Google map lifecycle:

```
package
{
    import com.google.maps.LatLng;
    import com.google.maps.Map;
    import com.google.maps.MapEvent;
    import com.google.maps.MapType;

    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.TimerEvent;
    import flash.geom.Point;
    import flash.utils.Timer;

    public class Test extends Sprite
    {

        private var _map:Map;

        private var _timer:Timer;

        public function Test()
        {
            super();

            createMap();

            _timer = new Timer(300000); // 5-min
            _timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerHandler);
            _timer.start();
        }

        private function timerHandler(event:TimerEvent):void
        {
            while (numChildren > 0)
                removeChildAt(0);

            createMap();
        }

        protected function createMap():void
        {
            _map = new Map();
            _map.key = "YOUR_API_KEY";
            _map.sensor = "false";
            _map.setSize(new Point(stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight));
            addChild(_map);

            _map.addEventListener(MapEvent.MAP_READY, mapReadyHandler);
        }

        protected function mapReadyHandler(event:MapEvent):void
        {
            _map.removeEventListener(MapEvent.MAP_READY, mapReadyHandler);
            _map.setCenter(new LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419), 13, MapType.NORMAL_MAP_TYPE);
        }

    }
}
```